# View Recently Appended Records in Destination Table

Tags: vba, ms-access, append

I have created an append query and afterward I want the newly appended records to display (complete with the ID autonumber in the destination table).

I tried creating a select query linking the original to the destination table, but this is giving me issues due to null or blank fields not matching and the possibility that one of the only definite filled in fields (name) could possibly match an earlier record (i.e. this is a table of contracts and a contract could have the same name, terminate, and then have a new contract created using the same name).

Is there any way, probably using VBA, to look at the max ID number in the destination table, run the append query, and then display all records in the destination table with an ID higher than the previous max?  I know how to run the append query using VBA, but having issues viewing the recently appended records.

Getting a Compile Error (wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment) - I'm still fairly new to VBA so perhaps I'm doing it wrong.  Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Ctl310_apqry_Click()
Dim lngID As Long
lngID = Nz(DMax("ContractID", "Contracts"), 0)
CurrentDb.Execute "310 apqry Add New Contract Records"
DoCmd.OpenTable "Contracts", acViewNormal, acEdit, "ContractID>" & lngID
End Sub
```

Comment: This may help https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200

Comment: Can't open a table or query with filter criteria that way. That's why my example opens a form.

Comment: oh sad - forms can't fit all the fields from this table in the datasheet view.  I'll just have to do a shortened version.  the code does work with the form - thanks so much for your help and expertise!

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, VBA can lookup max ID (DMax() can do that), run append query, open query/form/report of records filtered to ID greater than the former max ID. This does assume autonumber ID is positive and increasing which isn't supposed to be a guarantee although I've never seen otherwise.

Very simple example of code:

```
Dim lngID As Long
lngID = Nz(DMax("ID", "tablename"), 0)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "queryname"
DoCmd.OpenForm "formname", , , "ID>" & lngID
```

If you prefer to open a filtered query, options:

1. dynamic parameter in query - set an unbound textbox on form with max ID and then query can reference that textbox or code sets a TempVar and query references that
2. use QueryDefs in VBA to modify query object with filter criteria

Comment: edited my post above - your code looks easy enough but it's giving me a compile error - any ideas why?